# Filter and summarize data based on more than one critera

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I want to filter and summarize a list based on more than one criteria.

This data

```
Name    Sport   Victories
Daniel  Tennis  1
Esther  Tennis  1
Daniel  Archery 3
Mary    Tennis  2
Mary    Tennis  1
Mary    Archery 2
Esther  Tennis  2
```

should render a separate list such as this:

```
Name    Sport   Victories
Daniel  Tennis  1
Daniel  Archery 3
Esther  Tennis  3
Mary    Tennis  3
Mary    Archery 2
```

As you can see, the second list is a filtered version of the first. In the first list, we can see that Mary has played tennis two times but in the second list the combination of Mary and tennis only occurs once. Furthermore, in the second list the number of victories for each sport and person has been summarized.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Excel? Filter the first list based on two criterias (person and sport) and then count the number of victories based on the same criterias?

I have Office 365.

Comment: Pivot Table is probably the easiest.

Comment: Power Query may help you.